# MATLAB: Failed to create geometry. The stl file is invalid, more than two facets share an edge

Tags: matlab

im trying to create a crater alpha shape.
this is what i wrote so far:

```
ddr=0.12;
a=1/ddr/2; %semi major axis. horizontal axes are equal 
n=91; %number of points for x y vectors.
x = linspace(-a,a,n);
y = linspace(-a,a,n);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z =real(sqrt(1-(X.^2)/a^2-(Y.^2)/a^2))*-1+1; % the plus 1 for Z>0
shp = alphaShape(X(:),Y(:),Z(:));
plot(shp);
[elements,nodes] = boundaryFacets(shp);
nodes = nodes';
elements = elements';
model = createpde();
geometryFromMesh(model,nodes,elements);
```

but im getting the following error:
Failed to create geometry. The stl file is invalid, more than two facets share an edge.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that the problem comes only because of the interface of one object over the another (possibly there are more than one objects in your geometry), even though there are no overlaps. Try import a single object instead of importing the whole geometry.

Another solution is to convert your stl file to faces and vertices using stlread.m
and reconstruct the geometry.
Good luck!